# preact async router doesn't find chunk

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, preact

I'm quite new to react.js (using preact) and run into a problem with async routing (preact-async-router).

My main.js:

```
import { h, render } from 'preact';
import {Router, Route} from 'preact-router';
import AsyncRoute from 'preact-async-route';
import Home from './components/home.jsx';

/** @jsx h */

function getHelloWorld(){
    return System.import('./components/hello.jsx').then(module => module.default);
}

render(
    <Router>
        <Route path="/" component={Home} />
        <AsyncRoute path="/hello/:foo" component={getHelloWorld}
        loading={()=>{alert("loading...");}} />
    </Router>
, document.getElementById("app")
);
```

My home.jsx:

```
import {h, Component} from 'preact';
import {Link} from 'preact-router';

/** @jsx h */

export default class Home extends Component {
    render() {
        return <h1>
            This is home page<br/>
            <Link href='/hello/Earth'>Earth</Link>
        </h1>;
    }
}
```

My hello.jsx:

```
import {h, render, Component} from 'preact';

/** @jsx h */

export default class Hello extends Component {
    render() {
        return <h1>Hello {this.props.matches.foo}!</h1>
    }
}
```

Webpack creates the bundle.js and the 1.bundle.js (for hello.jsx)!

All in my resources-dir (resource-dir is via express.static available).

The home.jsx got loaded and the link points to (localhost/hello/Earth).

The problem now is that 1.bundle.js isn't getting loaded!
The Browser(bundle.js) is requesting the file under "/hello/1.bundle.js" and not under "/resources/1.bundle.js"!

How can I fix that?

EDIT:

It  works now. Added "publicPath" with "/resources/" to my webpack config. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Kian - seems like you need to set output.publicPath to "/" in your webpack configuration.

Answer (score 1):

as Jason said, see that you have this publicPath in the output, `publicPath` directs where these chunks have to be picked from.

[image: webpack config]

Answer (score 0):

You can also specify [name] in *filename* (if you want *publicPath* to stay /):

```
output: {
    filename: './dist/[name].bundle.js'
},
```

Then all js bundle files will be in *dist* directory